# I want to redirect to another page using angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to redirect to another page of the application. In the similar manner as we do in MVC application or asp.net application. I have defined the Route.js file which is below.

route.js defined in the following manner

```
var MainApp=angular.module('RoutingApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/BusinessAgent', {
                templateUrl: 'Views/BusinessAgent/BusinessAgent.html',
                controller: 'BusinessAgentController'
            })
        .when('/Admin', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/Admin/Admin.html'
        })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
    }]);
```

HTML page

```
 <section id="banner">        
        <ul class="actions">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#BusinessAgent" class="button big">Business Agent</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
    </section>
```

On click of href it should redirect.But it is not getting redirected.

Comment: Any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing ng-view . add ng-view for routing. It works as placeholder

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Comment: it should be Partial view. It should redirect to new page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html5Mode enabled

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

Then replace '#' with '/' in href

```
<a href="/BusinessAgent" class="button big">Business Agent</a>
```

if you disabled html5Mode then use

```
<a href="#/BusinessAgent" class="button big">Business Agent</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the url of controller instead of view there. 
Instead of

```
 $routeProvider
        .when('/BusinessAgent', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/BusinessAgent/BusinessAgent.html',
            controller: 'BusinessAgentController'
        })
```

Try using this.

```
           $routeProvider
        .when('/BusinessAgent', {
            templateUrl: 'ControllerName/Actionname',
            controller: 'BusinessAgentController'
  })
```

If you are trying to get different view, then use partial view for the respective action of controller.

Answer (score 0):

for me I like to use $urlRouterProvider rather than  $routeProvider see the below example:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/BusinessAgent");

        $stateProvider
        .state("BusinessAgent", {
            url: "/BusinessAgent",
            templateUrl: "Views/BusinessAgent/BusinessAgent.html",
            controller: "BusinessAgentController"
        });
```

that's mean you will call the state with **sref** rather than **href** like this:

```
<a sref="BusinessAgent" >BusinessAgent</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you used Angular UI-Router.

This is what I used in a recent application.Use the `ui-sref` tag instead of the href one.

```
<a ui-sref="/">Back to home</a>

<a ui-sref="cafe">Back to Cafe State</a>
```

I've used state provider instead of route provider.My states are

**Root State**

```
$stateProvider.state('/',{
    url:"/",
    templateUrl:'js/apps/choiceScreen/choice.html',  
    controller:'choiceCtrl'
})
```

**Cafe State**

```
.state('cafe',{

templateUrl:'js/apps/cafe/cafeScreen.html',
        controller:'cafeCtrl'
});
```

Comment: Can you example as have never used the $stateProvider

Answer (score -2):

you can use

```
$window.location.href = '/index.html';
```

for redurect to another page